# Series for $\text{Arg}( \zeta (z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

Though I don't know if the formula I've found is useful, I decided to publish it anyway.
$$
\text{Arg}( \zeta (z))
=
-\sum_ {k = 1}^{\infty}\sum _ {q = 1}^{\infty}\frac {1} {k P_q^{k x}}\text {Sin}( k y \text{ Log}(P_q ) ) \text{ , } |z|>1
$$

where $z=x+i y$ and $p_q$ is th $q^{th}$ prime number.

Here is an example with a plot of $\text{Arg}( \zeta (1+i y))$ in blue, and a plot of the sum in red:
[image]

My question is whether the formula is known, whether someone finds it helpful.

EDIT: this post was put 'on hold'. I don't know why. I'm a graphist and foreigner to the mathematics' community, thus it's very hard for me to check the results I got, and this is the reason of this post.

EDIT 2: If someone's interested, this other post shows at the end how the series was calculated [simple tools to extract Re, Im, Abs... of any complex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593830/simple-tools-to-extract-re-im-abs-of-any-complex-function)

Comment: What is $P_q $?

Comment: I don't know what is Pq but this is superb, even better than the previous you posted ! How many terms did you sum for the red line ?

Comment: I am surprised that the sum is over the primes and not the von Mangoldt function. Wonderful result of yours.

Comment: @claude, only ten terms..

Comment: @mats, I will post

Comment: crosspost http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150563/serie-for-argzetaz

Comment: @mats, the way i calculated this serie is in this post: [simple tools...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593830/simple-tools-to-extract-re-im-abs-of-any-complex-function)

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen anything like this before. Here is some code for the plot, apparently with a different scale factor:

```
(*Mathematica*)
Clear[a, k, q, y, x]
x = 1;
Monitor[a = 
   N[Table[-Sum[
       Sum[1/(k*Prime[q]^(k*x))*Sin[k*y*Log[Prime[q]]], {q, 1, 
         50}], {k, 1, 100}], {y, 1, 50, 1/4}]];, Floor[N[y]]]
g1 = ListLinePlot[a, DataRange -> {1, 50}, PlotStyle -> Red]
g2 = Plot[Arg[Zeta[1 + I*y]], {y, 1, 50}]
Show[g1, g2]
```